# How to get and set custom metadata values in Alfresco via REST API?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Please help me to get/set metadata by REST API Calls.I am Using Alfresco 5.0 version.

Comment: What REST APIs did you try? Did you try looking at the Alfresco API documentation? Did you try CMIS?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the [Alfresco REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/RESTful-intro.html) is limited to a small subset wich doesn't support (custom) metadata. Alfresco expects you use CMIS instead. Since CMIS may be too complicated / an overkill to integrate in your use case you could still create your own WebScripts to enable RESTful methods as you expect. This is straight forward. Take a look into the [Web_Scripts_Examples](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts_Examples) and the official [Web Scripts Documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-webscripts.html)

Comment: Thanx for the reply.
i got the below one  

URL:http://172.26.44.33:8084/alfresco/service/api/metadata/node/workspace/SpacesStore/ffde72f9-e1b1-4936-9b25-f5fbb6d9dd40?alf_ticket=TICKET_02011c9811d720ca945c1c282686a4b61fc41e22

METHOD: POST
JSON IP:
{
    "properties": {
        "kb:documentRef": "PARTNERID VIA API"
    }
}

JSON OP : 
{
   "success": true
}

Comment: right - I missed that. Thanks for the feedback. If you're fine with posting json that's your solution. But be careful: If I remember right you can pass any property and Alfresco writes them to the node without validating against the model. But maybe this is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find details of all existing rest api on below link

http://host:port/alfresco/service/index/all

If the api does not exist on above than you need to create your custom one.I am not sure about metadata.But you can find it on above link.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.
i got the below one  

URL:http://172.26.44.33:8084/alfresco/service/api/metadata/node/workspace/SpacesStore/ffde72f9-e1b1-4936-9b25-f5fbb6d9dd40?alf_ticket=TICKET_02011c9811d720ca945c1c282686a4b61fc41e22

METHOD: POST
JSON IP:
{
    "properties": {
        "kb:documentRef": "PARTNERID VIA API"
    }
}

JSON OP : 
{
   "success": true
}

Comment: I meant you can find all webservices(rest api) on above url